# How to specify linewidth in Seaborn's clustermap dendrograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Normally I would increase matplotlib's global linewidths by editing the matplotlib.rcParams. This seems to work well directly with [SciPy's dendrogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) implementation but not with [Seaborn's clustermap](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) (which uses SciPy's dendrograms). Can anyone suggest a working method?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 10
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
g = sns.clustermap(flights)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has now been addressed in a more robust way by the following merged pull request https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/1935. I'm assuming it will be included in the release after v0.9.0.

You can control the `LineCollection` properties of the dendrogram by using the `tree_kws` parameter.

For example:

```
>>> import seaborn as sns
>>> iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
>>> species = iris.pop("species")
>>> g = sns.clustermap(iris, tree_kws=dict(linewidths=1.5, colors=(0.2, 0.2, 0.4))
```

Would create a clustermap with 1.5 pt thick lines for the tree in an alternative dark purple color.

Answer (score 2):

There may be an easier way to do it, but this seems to work:

```
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
g = sns.clustermap(flights)
for l in g.ax_row_dendrogram.lines:
        l.set_linewidth(10)
for l in g.ax_col_dendrogram.lines:
        l.set_linewidth(10)
```

**Edit** This no longer works in Seaborn v. 0.7.1 (and probably some earlier versions as well); `g.ax_col_dendrogram.lines` now returns an empty list.  I couldn't find a way to increase line width and I ended up temporarily modifying the Seaborn module.  In file `matrix.py`, function `class _DendrogramPlotter`, the linewidth is hard-coded as 0.5; I modified it to 1.5:

`line_kwargs = dict(linewidths=1.5, colors='k')`

This worked but obviously isn't a very sustainable approach.

Comment: This method worked as expected. It's also a better implementation than trying to force the rcParams to take precedence.

Comment: Just as an FYI: This method no longer seems to work. I'll look into it further and if I find something I'll report back.

Comment: @clintval any progress?

Answer (score 2):

for newer versions of seaborn (tested with 0.7.1, 0.9.0), the lines are in a LineCollection, rather than by themselves. So their width can be changed as follows:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data and make clustermap
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
g = sns.clustermap(df[['sepal_length', 'sepal_width']])

for a in g.ax_row_dendrogram.collections:
    a.set_linewidth(10)

for a in g.ax_col_dendrogram.collections:
    a.set_linewidth(10)
```