# How to suppress drawing dendrograms but still cluster in seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to plot a clustermap in seaborn, clustered by both rows and columns. I do not want to draw the dendrograms.

Setting `row_cluster=False` or `col_cluster=False` removes the dendrograms, but also stops the clustering.

**How do I still 2D cluster but suppress the dendrograms?**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155864/how-to-specify-linewidth-in-seaborns-clustermap-dendrograms) provides a hack of setting the width of the dendrogram lines to 0. This hack does not work in seaborn `0.7.1`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The answer is buried in the documentation.

Let `cg` be the clustermap instance returned by Seaborn.

After drawing the clustermap, type the following to remove the row dendrogram.

`cg.ax_row_dendrogram.set_visible(False)`

If you want to preserve the legend, type:

`cg.ax_row_dendrogram.set_xlim([0,0])`

This is a hack, but `set_axis_off()` does not seem to do in Seaborn what it does in matplotlib.

Comment: What are you expecting `set_axis_off` to do?

Comment: Make the axes invisible. The frame would still, of course, be visible.

Comment: I had to add `cm.ax_cbar.set_visible(False)` as well to hide the cbar tick labels!

Answer (score 1):

To build on the answer by mac389, if you want to suppress the dendrogram in both columns and rows do the following:

```
cg.ax_row_dendrogram.set_visible(False) #suppress row dendrogram

cg.ax_col_dendrogram.set_visible(False) #suppress column dendrogram
```

You can also suppress the cbar as indicated by Yacine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the easiest way to do that would be by using the `tree_kwd` argument to set the `linewidts` parameter of the underlying `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection` object to zero.

```
clustermap(YOUR_DATA, tree_kws={"linewidths": 0.})
```